# Kill session variables when exiting browser in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am looking for a solution on how to get ColdFusion to end the user's session when the users closes their browser.

In other words, when the user exits the browser I want them to re-login.

I have tried many solution to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is the latest code I got to insert in the application.cfm which would reset the session variable. Unfortunately it did not work.

```
<cfif IsDefined("Cookie.CFID") AND IsDefined("Cookie.CFTOKEN")>
    <cfset Variables.cfid_local = Cookie.CFID>
    <cfset Variables.cftoken_local = Cookie.CFTOKEN>
    <cfcookie name="CFID" value="#Variables.cfid_local#">
    <cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="#Variables.cftoken_local#">
</cfif>


    <CFPARAM NAME="session.allowin" DEFAULT="false" />
     <CFPARAM NAME="session.user_id" DEFAULT="0" />


    <cfif session.allowin neq "true">
        <cfif  ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/") EQ "login.cfm">
        <cfelseif ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/") EQ "login_process.cfm">
        <cfelse>
            <!--- this user is not logged in, alert user and redirect to the login.cfm page --->
            <script>
                alert("You must login to access this area!");
                self.location="login.cfm";
            </script>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to Application.cfc and using the OnSessionStart-Method?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but it should provide you with a relevant starting place...  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1847-explicitly-ending-a-coldfusion-session.htm

Answer (score 4):

> create session-only cookies.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1131-ask-ben-ending-coldfusion-session-when-user-closes-browser.htm

or

> enabling J2EE session variables in CF Admin

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1131-ask-ben-ending-coldfusion-session-when-user-closes-browser.htm#comments_7931

Comment: Keep in mind that while either of these suggestions will solve the problem at hand, neither will actually 'kill' the session when the browser is closed, rather, it will force a new session when browser is reopened. The old session will still live in memory until it times out.